# dojo dgrid tree, subrows in wrong position

Tags: javascript, dojo, tree, position, dgrid

I have a dgrid, working with tree column plugin. Every time that the user click on the tree, I call the server, catch the subrows(json) and bind it. But when it happens, these subrows are show in wrong position, like the image bellow. The most strange is when I change the pagination, after go back to first page, the subrows stay on the correct place.

(please, tell me if is possible to understand my english, then I can try to improve the text)

[image: dgrid with wrong position subrows]

My dgrid code:

```
  var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, Pagination]);

    var grid = new CustomGrid({
        columns: [
            selector({label: "#", disabled: function(object){ return object.type == 'DOCx'; }}, "radio"),
            {label:'Id', field:'id', sortable: false},
            tree({label: "Title", field:"title", sortable: true, indentWidth:20, allowDuplicates:true}),
            //{label:'Title', field:'title', sortable: false},
            {label:'Count', field:'count', sortable: false}
        ],
        store: this.memoryStore,
        collapseOnRefresh:true,
        pagingLinks: false,
        pagingTextBox: true,
        firstLastArrows: true,
        pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 25],
        selectionMode: "single", // for Selection; only select a single row at a time
        cellNavigation: false // for Keyboard; allow only row-level keyboard navigation
    }, "grid");
```

My memory store:

```
loadMemoryStore: function(items){

            this.memoryStore = Observable(new Memory({
                data: items,
                getChildren: function(parent, options){
                    return this.query({parent: parent.id}, options);
                },
                mayHaveChildren: function(parent){
                    return (parent.count != 0) && (parent.type != 'DOC');
                }

            }));

        },
```

This moment I am binding the subrows:

```
        success: function(data){

            for(var i=0; i<data.report.length; i++){
                this.memoryStore.put({id:data.report[i].id, title:data.report[i].created, type:'DOC', parent:this.designId});
            }

        },
```

I was thinking, maybe every moment that I bind the subrows, I could do like a refresh on the grid, maybe works. I think that the pagination does the same thing.

Thanks.

edit:

I forgot the question. Well, How can I correct this bug? If The refresh in dgrid works. How can I do it? Other thing that I was thinking, maybe my getChildren is wrong, but I could not identify it.

thanks again.

Comment: I am trying, but without success to do it works. I can't believe that nobody has an example like this. All here load your subrows before to load the grid?

You have more performance if you load your subitems after the user's choice.

Nobody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My solution was change from PARENT hierarquia to CHILDREN hierarquia. Now works fine.

My dgrid code:

```
this.mapReportItems(reportDAO.get()); 
            //this.mapReportItems(x); 
            this.loadMemoryStore(this.reportItems); 

            var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, Keyboard, Selection, Pagination]); 

            var grid = new CustomGrid({ 
                columns: [ 
                    selector({label: "#", disabled: function(object){ return object.type == 'DOCx'; }}, "radio"), 
                    {label:'Id', field:'id', sortable: false}, 
                    tree({label: "Title", field:"title", sortable: false, indentWidth:20, shouldExpand:function() { return 0; }}), 
                    //{label:'Title', field:'title', sortable: false}, 
                    {label:'Count', field:'count', sortable: true} 
                ], 
                query: {parent: parent.children }, 
                store: this.memoryStore, 
                deselectOnRefresh: false, 
                //columnReordering:true, 
                collapseOnRefresh:false, 
                pagingLinks: false, 
                pagingTextBox: true, 
                firstLastArrows: true, 
                pageSizeOptions: [10, 15, 25], 
                selectionMode: "single", // for Selection; only select a single row at a time 
                cellNavigation: false // for Keyboard; allow only row-level keyboard navigation 
            }, "grid");
```

My memory store:

this.memoryStore = Observable(new Memory({ 
            data: items, 
            getChildren: function(parent){

```
            return parent.children; 
        }, 

        mayHaveChildren: function(parent){ 
            //return (parent.count != 0) && (parent.type != 'DOC'); 
            return (parent.children && parent.children.length) || (parent.count != 0 && parent.type != 'DOC'); 
        } 

    }));
```

This moment I am binding the subrows:

```
success: function(data){ 

                    var node = this.memoryStore.get(this.designId); 

                    for(var i=0; i<data.report.length; i++){ 
                        node.children.push({id:data.report[i].id, title:data.report[i].created, type:'DOC'}); 
                    } 

                    this.memoryStore.put(node); 
                    this.data = data; 
                },
```

Extra information. In my case I need map my Json data, this way:

```
   this.reportItems = dojo.map(jsondata.reportDesign, function(report) {
                return {
                    //'@uri': report[1],
                    id : report.id,
                    title : report.title,
                    count : report.count,
                    children: [],//report.children,
                    type : report.type
                    //parent : report.parent
                };
            });
```

This link was useful for me:
https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/issues/346